# Coaxial Switch Using Arduino and Multiplexers

Tags: arduino, video

Hi maybe someone can help me here, basically I am trying to build a computer controlled coaxial switch. I am using a regular Integrated circuit multiplexer to handle which channel is patched to output. So basically I have:

```
              (8 X Coaxial Inputs)
              I I I I I I I I
```

microcontroller ----> | Multiplexer | --------------- I (1 X Coaxial Output)

The idea is so that I can use a computer to control which of my 8 video feeds that I can watch. I thought that because the connections are straight through I wouldn't have to worry about attenuation as much, but I tried a sample setup using a breadboard and I can barely see the picture. Any ideas as to how I can make it work?

I am currently using a breadboard with all the components I listed Plus some small gauge cables (so that they fit on the bread board)

UPDATE:
This is what My setup Looks like http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/6320/49195403.png
the MUX is a UTC 4051 Data Sheet is Here http://alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/173652/UTC/4051.html

Comment: Can you give us more detail on how exactly is everything connected? A picture of the breadboard maybe? Are you sure that you connected shields properly?

Comment: This is close to how it should look, How am I supposed to shield the cables? I am new to dealing with hardware... I am literally soldering a cable from the coxial inputs straight into an input on the multiplexer.... http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/6320/49195403.png

Comment: I meant the actual picture of the hardware you have. Anyway, what I meant to say is that the shields of the coaxial cables should be connected together. Also there is no such thing as `regular Integrated circuit multiplexer`. Give us the exact model number. Also I believe that the multiplexer could be attenuating the signal, so that's why the exact model is important.

Comment: With projects such as this one, the problem is that in order to maintain the signal quality, you need to have matched impedance along the whole cable and the multiplexer is going to cause problems there. Also the breadboard could be a problem. The frequencies used by TV systems are an order of magnitude larger than frequencies for which breadboards are designed, so you could have all sorts of problems from that.

Comment: lol Sorry I know I sound like a total NUB the MUX is a UTC 4051 Data Sheet is Here http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/173652/UTC/4051.html

Comment: Micro Controller is an (OSEEP) Arduino UNO

Comment: OK, that's a lot better. You have to start somewhere :). It would be a good idea to put such information in the text of the question itself, so that people can find the information without having to look at the whole comments section. Next, I see in the datasheet several interesting points: First, take a look at the ON Resistance part on the datasheet. At 5 V, you have between 250 Ohms and 2050 Ohms and you need 50 Ohms. Then you have bandwidth which is just 17 MHz and for TV, you'll need much more. I too probably missed some important points.

Comment: So the part isn't suitable for the use. Unfortunately, I don't have a good suggestion for replacement. If I had to figure out how to do this right now, I'd pick relays for each input channel, all hard wires to same output and active one at a time, but this has its own problems. They are expensive and require few more components to control. Someone is probably going to provide a better answer.

Comment: what If i converted all my coaxial cables to composite... Would that help if I only dealt with data coming in as Composite Video?

Comment: That to me looks like a good idea. If Google is giving me right information, the composite should be capable of going through the multiplexer. The ON resistance problem will remain, but I think that if you should try with that if you can. If it turns out that the only problem is on resistance, maybe it would be possible to build a small amplifier to deal with that.

Comment: So I would have to amplify the output after it comes out of the MUX?

Comment: http://jap.hu/electronic/avswitch.gif looks like I can build this using my current components, can u explain what is going on in the top right corner of the diagram it looks like they are using a resister I think...?

Comment: Well try it first without anything and see how it looks. I'd rather amplify the signal before it goes into the multiplexer, if possible. My reasoning here is that it would be better to amplify good quality signal at the input than the damaged signal at the output. The problem that I'm expecting here is that the multiplexer will drop the signal voltage and that it won't be readable at the receiver.  I have a feeling that the amplified could be built so that its cost would be in the <$2 range, so it would be feasible to have one at each input, but I'm not an amplifier expert.

Comment: The top right corner is an amplifier. The transistor amplifies the signal. The capacitor allows only the AC component (which is carrying data) to pass through, the diode stops the AC component from going into the power supply and allows the DC current to go from the supply. Since the capacitor only passes the AC current, the DC current goes into the base of the transistor and provides a DC signal on which the AC signal will "ride". The R3 and R4 provide bias for the transistor (since it needs minimal voltage at the base to turn on), the R1 limits the current going into the base.

Comment: Cont. And the R1 also sets the amplification here. R2 is used to limit the current going out of the transistor and to provide appropriate voltage level going into the output line. All in all the amplifier is pretty simple and very cheap.

Comment: Also check Wikipedia for names of components I mentioned to see their schematic markings.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://bit.ly/HXuTNu) simulation (sorry for the link shortener, but whole link won't fit in an answer). The green signal on the left bottom is what is coming into the amplifier and the green signal on the bottom right is what is coming out of the amplifier. As you can see, the signal on the right is much stronger than the signal on the left. That's what's happening in the circuit to the right of the link you provided.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you didn't buffer the output.

If you tried to direct drive your 75ohm load, you would  discover a lot of attenuation from the 250ohm switch resistance.

Use 10K load or so and buffer the output with a 75ohm line driver or whatever you can buffer with 10MHz BW or so.
Consider how critical your levels need to be and matched source impedance to 75 ohm. Ideally everything sourced to your monitor is 75ohm for NTSC composite video.

I hope that works and my intuition is correct.

Comment: OK Thanks So much for the feedback guys.. so I found out that my problem was that I wasn't grounding my cables correctly.. I have also moved on to using Component cables instead of RCA (I just happen to have RCA terminators that I can easily attach cables to)... Anyways Regrading how to create a buffer, I purchased NTE947D OP AMP data sheet is here -> http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/nte/NTE947D.pdf HOW DO I Connect this up to my current setup? I see that it has 2 channels but I will only be using one channel to do this right? I am a little lost as to how I am supposed to hook this up

Comment: (Is my output Video Signal from the MUX going to be the Invert Input??? and my final OUTPUT RCA going to be the Output A???)